# Suite CRM Installation

Tags: apache, installation, crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm trying to install Suite CRM on a 2011 Mac Mini running El Capitan and with the "Mac Server App" installed.

I've unzipped the Suite CRM package under /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Suite however when I enter the following

```
chgrp _www.www /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Suite -R
```

I get the error

```
chgrp: _www._www: illegal group name
```

I've checked I'm using the right Apache user and group so I'm stuck. Should I unzip SuiteCRM in a different location? Is it something to do with the Mac Server App?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It think you need to use `sudo`:

`sudo chown -R _www:_www <mywebfolder>`

`sudo chmod -R 775 <mywebfolder>`

Answer (score 0):

To install Suite CRM, which is compatible almost with every OS there is the procedure of following steps:

1. After downloading the SuiteCRM (if you are installing it first time otherwise you will have to upgrade the existing one), click on install.
2. Pre requisite for SuiteCRM are platform appropriate version of PHP, web server and database on your machine (Linux or Windows platform)
3. Unzip the downloaded SuiteCRM package and set permissions. For this, while unzipping the package locate the root directory or sub directory of your web server.
4. You can rename the SuiteCRM as well
5. Set permissions or ownership of your SuiteCRM directory with the following command: `Chgrp ApacheUser.ApacheGroup <suitecrmroot> -R`
6. Now set the system user of your web server. If you find it difficult to set the permissions for system user then you can take the help of any expert.  From there you can take the help. Commonly the users are apache or nobody for Linux and `IUSR_computerName` for Windows. For Linux following commands are to be executed in order to set the permissions: `sudo chown –R www-data:www-data;sudo chmod –R 755; sudo chmod –R 775 cache custom modules themes data upload config_override.php`

While for Windows the steps are different. You can also take the help of any expert if you find it difficult to set up the Suite CRM, then any training or service provider of technical courses can help you in this regard. We have used the service of Janbask, they are professional training provider and IT consultants, with the help of their experts they also provide solutions of real time problems.

Many Thanks